# Check a checkbox when the other is checked in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Currently I have 3 checkboxes in gridview which are Approval,Access and Edit. What I want to achieve is when I checked the Edit column, the Access column will be checked automatically too. Is there any way to solve this? I have looked through a lot internet source but still not able to do it. Please help me..

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="65%">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Module" HeaderText="Module" SortExpression="Module" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approval">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBApproval" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBAccess" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBEdit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"/> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC00" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Bind both of them to the same property in your viewmodel.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Can you explain it in a clearer form? Coz I don't really get your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinc edit checkbox postback you may set the value of accessed checkbox from codebehind.. Add new event to edit checkbox on click and set new value for accessed checkbox.checked